# Extract rows into a limited template based on multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, data-transfer, extract

I have an issue in extracting from "Datadump" into several continuous "Template" (as the template can only contain 10 rows of item).

Here are my intentions:

1. From the data dump (sample above), is it possible to automatically extract the appropriate value into the Template with a maximum of 10 rows for each set of Template. And then colour-code those that have been printed to the Template.
   [image: Template]
   These are the Template (Payment Voucher) limitations:

   a. Each template contains the data from only **1 (one) day**

If in 1st January 2020 & 2nd January 2020, there are 5 transactions **/day**, there would have to be **2 Templates (1 for each day).**

b. Each Template should only be from **1 Source**

So if in 1st January 2020 & 2nd January 2020, there are 5 transactions/day from **each Source A & B**, there would be **4 Templates (1 for each source/day)**.

c. Each template could only contain **10 lines.**

So if in 1st January 2020 & 2nd January 2020, there are **11** transactions/day from each Source A & B, there would be **8 Templates (2 for each source/day)**.

I have also attached a Before and After for reference :)

**Before:**

[image: Before]

[image: Template]

**After:**

[image: After]

[image: Voucher Page 1]

[image: Voucher Page 2]

Since I am new to VBA, I would have no issue with the inputs to their appropriate places and to colour code. But I am still learning about the loop function that I believe would be required for this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

@Edit:

Values for the templates are:

```
1. Credit Source = Source + Source Name
2. Total = All values inside the voucher
3. Account = Item Code
4. Detail = Item Name
5. Unit Code = Unit Code
6. Value = Total Debit
```

Here are the codes that I could come up with for now (Trying to break the process down)

@edit @edit

```
Sub learn()
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set dtws = Worksheets("Database")
Set wstr = Worksheets("trial")
Dim vcdate
vcdate = wstr.Cells(2, "B").Value
Dim vcsource
vcsource = wstr.Cells(2, "D").Value

Dim NoE As Long
Dim lmtcount As Long

'Limiting No. Of Entries

'With wstr
 '   .Cells(2, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(dtws.Range("A:A"), vcdate, dtws.Range("J:J"), vcsource)

 '   NoE = wstr.Cells(2, 1).Value

'If NoE < 11 Then
'    .Cells(2, 3).Value = NoE
'Else
'    .Cells(2, 3).Value = 10

'End If
'End With

'lmtcount = wstr.Cells(2, 3).Value

'MsgBox NoE
'End of Limiting No. Of Entries


'------------------------
'Inputting Appropriately
'------------------------

Set tempws = Worksheets("Template")

Dim lrow As Long
Dim Count1 As Long

For Count1 = 1 To 100
    lrow = tempws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox lrow
    If lrow = 19 Then Exit For
    '-----------------------------------------
    'MsgBox dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, "A").Value
    '-----------------------------------------
    'Cross-Check if the same date
    If CDate(dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, "A").Value) > CDate(vcdate) Then Exit For
    '-----------------------------------------
    'Cross check error
    'MsgBox dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, "A").Value
    'MsgBox dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, "J").Value
    '-----------------------------------------
    If dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, "J").Value2 = vcsource Then
        With tempws
            .Cells(lrow + 1, "A") = dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, 2)
            .Cells(lrow + 1, "C") = dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, 3) & " - " & dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, 5)
            .Cells(lrow + 1, "G") = dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, 6)
            .Cells(lrow + 1, "I") = dtws.Cells(Count1 + 1, 9)
        End With
       '-----------------------------------------
       'Colour Code
       '-----------------------------------------
       With dtws
            .Cells(Count1 + 1, 2).Interior.Color = 13998939
            .Cells(Count1 + 1, 3).Interior.Color = 13998939
            .Cells(Count1 + 1, 6).Interior.Color = 13998939
            .Cells(Count1 + 1, 9).Interior.Color = 13998939
        End With


    End If


Next Count1


With tempws
        .Cells(20, "I").Formula = "=sum(I10:I19)"
        .Cells(7, "C").Value = tempws.Cells(20, "I").Value
        .Cells(4, "J").Value = vcdate
        .Cells(6, "C").Value = vcsource

End With

'----------------------------------------
'Input Tracking Order
'----------------------------------------
lrowtr = wstr.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With wstr
    .Cells(lrowtr + 1, "A").Value = vcsource
    .Cells(lrowtr + 1, "B").Value = vcdate
    .Cells(lrowtr + 1, "C").Value = Count1
End With
'----------------------------------------
'End of Input Tracking order
'----------------------------------------

End Sub
```

I believe I would not have an issue with the colour coding but it seems that the data extraction is the main issue...

Any help would be appreciated!